# Problem displaying inserted form

Tags: wpdb

I've build a form and inserted its data into custom database tables using `$wpdb`.

When I click on the submit button, the page reloads and one row is added to the database, but nothing displays on website.

My insert code is:

```
function insert_form() {

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "food_resarved";
    $alibaba = $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'user_id' => wp_get_current_user()->ID,
            'name' => wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname,
            'lastname' => wp_get_current_user()->user_lastname,
            'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
            'food_selected' => $_POST['food'],
            'guest_number' => $_POST['guest_food'],
            'email' => wp_get_current_user()->user_email 
        ), 
        array( '%d', '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s', '%s' ) 
    );

    if ( !$alibaba ) {
        $mylink = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from wp_food_resarved where user_id like '".$curent_user."' AND post_title like '".$abcde."' ");
        foreach ($mylink as $posta){
            echo '<div class="ordered-food">';
            echo ' شما ';
            echo $posta->food_selected;
            echo ' سفارش داده‌اید ';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "Die";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide us some more information. Front-end, Back-end, which hooks are you using etc...

Comment: my content.php is: [link]http://notepad.cc/gelloni15. my index.php is: [link] http://notepad.cc/couriecy51. and my function.php is: [link]http://notepad.cc/laddibba30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code I encountered two problems.

1. First one is you have not defined `$current_user` and `$abcde` variable. For using global `$current_user` you need to define it in the top of the function as `global $current_user`. Otherwise it will not get the `$current_user` variable. And also for getting the current user ID yo need to use `$current_user->ID` after declaring the global variable. And for `$abcde` variable please declare or store the value first in that variable.
2. And second one is you are checking logic with `if (!$alibaba)` which actually means if the `$alibaba` variable is false. Obviously if the DB entry is successful the `$alibaba` will return true. So the loop will not be executed.

So now your whole code will be like below-

```
function insert_form() {

    global $wpdb, $current_user;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "food_resarved";
    $abcde = ''; // Later some where put a value in it. Otherwise it will not work.
    $alibaba = $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'id' => '',
            'user_id' => wp_get_current_user()->ID,
            'name' => wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname,
            'lastname' => wp_get_current_user()->user_lastname,
            'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
            'food_selected' => $_POST['food'],
            'guest_number' => $_POST['guest_food'],
            'email' => wp_get_current_user()->user_email
        ),
        array( '%d', '%s', '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s' , '%s', '%s' )
    );

    if ( $alibaba ) {
        $mylink = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from wp_food_resarved where user_id like '".$current_user->ID."' AND post_title like '".$abcde."' ");
        foreach ($mylink as $posta){
            echo '<div class="ordered-food">';
            echo ' شما ';
            echo $posta->food_selected;
            echo ' سفارش داده‌اید ';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Die";
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.